# RSpec includes help needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, rspec, require

I'm trying to mimic something similar to http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-2/dir/routing-specs/access-to-named-routes-in-routing-specs

I have a unit test passing:

```
    require 'test_helper'

    class RoutesTest < ActionController::TestCase
      test "book name is sent to store#index' do
        assert_routing 'book/mytitle', {:controller => 'book', :action => 'index', :title => 'mytitle'}
      end    
    end
```

I'm trying to covert this to an RSpec test (running Rspec 2.2 under Rails3.0.3)

Here's the test:

```
    require 'spec_helper'
    include RSpec::Rails::Matchers::RoutingMatchers
    include ActionDispatch::Assertions::RoutingAssertions

    describe "book specific routes" do
       it "should recognize title in path" do
         {:get => "book/mytitle"}.should route_to(:controller => "book", :action => "index", :title => "mytitle")
       end
    end
```

But this results in:

```
Failures:

  1) book specific routes should recognize title in path
     Failure/Error: {:get => "book/mytitle"}.should route_to(:controller => "book", :action => "index", :title => "mytitle")
     undefined method `recognize_path' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/route_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any idea where the nilClass is coming from? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the double include of `ActionDispatch::Assertions::RoutingAssertions` which causes the failure -- not sure why. Remove the two `include` statements and all should be well. The spec file should live in `/spec/routing`. You can wrap the example with `describe BooksController` for style points, but it will work without it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the matchers need to be used inside a controller spec. They should already be there, so there would be no need to include them manually. Just make sure you're describing a controller.

```
describe BooksController do
  it "should recognize title in path" do
    # ...
  end
end
```